# Python multiprocessing queue behavior

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
def f(x, y):
    def _f(x, y, queue):
        res = get_data(x, y)
        queue.put(res)

    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=_f, args=(x, y, q))
    p.start()
    res = q.get()
    p.join()

    return res
```

It works perfectly. But when I do `res = q.get()` after `p.join()` like this:

```
q = Queue()
p = Process(target=_f, args=(x, y, q))
p.start()
p.join()
return q.get()
```

For somewhat large data (e.g. several hundred elements of JSON array), it will hang at `p.join()`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting a race condition. If you care to look at `multiprocessing.Queue` source, you will notice that it uses a `multiprocessing.Pipe` and a `threading.Thread` in order to communicate among `multiprocessing.Process` instances. So, when you call `Queue.put`, you are actually asking the aforementioned thread to write a object to other `Process` using a `Connection.send` created by the `Pipe`. When you call `Queue.get`, you are actually consuming data you receive through `Connection.recv`, which constitute the other end of the `Pipe`.

Now, if you go deeper into `multiprocessing.Pipe` and the `Connection` instances it creates, you will find that they use OS low-level interfaces to implement most of their functionalities. However, by using such interfaces, the writer has to respect an upper limit on how much data it can feed to `Connection.send` without another `Process` or `Thread` calling the respective `Connection.recv`.

In your specific case, the `Process` for `_f` ends as soon as `queue.put(res)` returns (i.e., just after you "ask" the `Thread` to write `res`). The only thing preventing the `Process` to finish is the pending `Connection.send`; after that, it is free to go. If the object is small and respect the OS limit, `Conneciton.send` will return immediately and the whole process will finish. On the other hand, if the object is bigger than the OS limit, `Connection.send` will block waiting for a `Connection.recv` to free some space for the remaining data. However, this never happens because, just after you call `Process.start`, you call `Process.join`, which will block until the `Process` ends; an ending that will only happen after you to call `Connection.recv`; a call that will happen only after `Process.join` returns; and we close our deadlock chain.